# Possible to output to console from within a class library C#?

Tags: c#, console

Is it possible to output values to the console from within a class library?

For example

```
 Console App -> calls method in -> assembly > function
```

Is it possible to write a console.out method in the function of the assembly?

I know in web its possible to get the httpcontext, and do a response.write.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yup, `Console.WriteLine` etc will work just fine in a class library... but there's no guarantee that anything is *listening* to the console. If you use it from a WinForms app or a web app, that output may well go absolutely nowhere...

Have you thought of using a logging library such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) instead?

Comment: Thanks Jon, yes I use log4net. I am using this console stuff, just for 1 implementation for a presentation.

Comment: Jon, what do you mean by _listening_?

Comment: @YairNevet: I mean that although it won't fail, the output may not go anywhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet doesnt work for me. I have a Console Application that calls a .NET Standard Library and I get an unhandled exception message. "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken.....or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0,

Comment: @GeorgeGeschwend: I suggest you ask a new question with complete information (e.g. version of netstandard you're targeting, project file, type of console application etc). I use `Console.WriteLine` from netstandard libraries all the time, so it definitely *can* work, but we shouldn't go into the diagnostics in a comment thread on an answer that existed long before .NET Core started...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what type of application is going to use your class library. If it is used in a console application, then the output will be printed to the console. If it is a WinForms, Windows Service or ASP.NET application the output will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is, just use `System.Console.Write...`

Answer (score 3):

Sure if the library client is a Console app,  just call Console.WriteLine("") with your messages.

If you do not have a console based client and you want to open a Console for your own use then you need to use P/Invoke to call [ConsoleAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx). See [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=AllocConsole&namespace=[All]) for some help with the P/Invoke declaration.

Having said that I must also point out that writing to the console from a Class library is decidedly bad design and you should consider using the dot net tracing/logging mechanism instead (Peruse the Microsoft documentation on System.Diagnostics)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have a Console Application project in your solution, use Console.WriteLine(), as usual.
2. Otherwise, if you have a Class Library project, use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine().

The bad news:
- Your texts will be in the middle of all the lines in Output.
- You'll have to search them. I recommend you to select all the text in the Output and paste on a Notepad. It will be easier to find what you're looking for.

The good news:
- Your texts wil be alone in their lines. Only the result from your command System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine().

Comment: This answer was particularly useful for me and I found the 2nd option about System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() to be exactly what I was looking for.