# Console unavailable in class library c#

Tags: c#, console, class-library

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288294/possible-to-output-to-console-from-within-a-class-library-c) seems contrary to what I have experienced. I cannot access the console from within a new class library. I have `using System;` at the top. I am using visual studio 11 on windows 8. I doubt that this has been lost in the update, so that means that I am doing something wrong.

Also, once this is working, is the console available in a portable class library?

**EDIT**

here is just a test file I made

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdamLib.util.ConsoleSupport
{
    class SafeRead
    {
        private void test()
        {
            System.Console.Writeline("test"); //Console is not found in system
        }
    }
}
```

This is in the class library.

**RESOLVED**

Like I thought, it was my fault.

Thanks to @DarinDimitrov, who pointed out that with VS 11 and metro, Console support has been removed for use with metro. So to resolve this I needed to create a new project with the second kind of class library. There are two listed and I used the one **with** the description that includes metro. To resolve the issue, I had to use the other type **without** metro in the description.

Thanks again to all that helped.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: But the main project is a ConsoleApplication or a Windows Form?

Comment: I get `The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` and there is no main project yet. I am just writing my library of utilities.

Comment: Even if it's a Windows Form app the console would still be available, you just won't see it. We need more info. Does your app compile, runtime error, etc.?

Comment: It does not compile. It stops me with the above error.

Comment: **One possible work-around**: in my case, I was able to instantiate and use my PCL class from a console/wpf application. I can then print console messages from within the PCL by passing an Action<string> to my PCL class ctor. The Action I pass is `s => Console.WriteLine(s)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you created a Metro style application, there's no Console in WinRT. Don't search for it as you won't find any. This is explained in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The subset of managed types and members was designed with a clear
>   focus on Metro style app development. As a result, it omits the
>   following:
>
> - Types and members that are not applicable to developing Metro style apps (such as console and ASP.NET types).
> - Obsolete and legacy types.
> - Types that overlap with Windows Runtime types.
> - Types and members that wrap operating system functionality (such as
>     System.Diagnostics.EventLog and performance counters).
> - Members that cause confusion (such as the Close method on I/O types).

You could use the [debugging API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) or logging framework.

Comment: On top of that, unless this class lib is supposed to be some kind of view component, you wouldn't want to write to a console.  Write to a/the log.

Comment: Its a collection of some utilities I wrote for use with the command line. So I need to interact with it.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone, if you need to interact with a console, don't create a WinRT class library as the notion of Console doesn't exist in Windows 8 Metro style.

Comment: So because of metro, I cannot access the console?

Comment: @AdamSchiavone, yes, because of Metro you cannot access Console. There's no such thing as Console in Metro.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to just make a library for console apps only?

Comment: @AdamSchiavone, of course that it is possible. You just need to target a standard .NET class library when creating it, not Metro.

Comment: Depending of what you want to do with the Console, this guys may help you: http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/ConsoleClass/, they have released a drop down replacement for the Console Class that works on Metro, but rigth now, it's a beta version.

Answer (score 9):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz(v=vs.110).aspx