# The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context In xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a app in Xamarin Forms that needs to get the geolocation data from the device and then put the geolocation coordinates into the forecast.io URL I am using the Geolocator plugin by James Montemagno and i'm using the code that the read me suggests, however I get the following error 4 times:

> The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Here's my code:

```
using AppName.Data;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;

namespace AppName.Radar
{    
    public partial class RadarHome : ContentPage
    {   
        public RadarHome()
        {    
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeout: 10000);

            Console.WriteLine("Position Status: {0}", position.Timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine("Position Latitude: {0}", position.Latitude);
            Console.WriteLine("Position Longitude: {0}", position.Longitude);
            var LatLong = position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude;

            var browser = new WebView();
            browser.Source = "https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/" + LatLong;

            Content = browser;   
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Update 3. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well aside from anything else, if you're trying to use `System.Console`, you're missing a `using System;` directive. But I've no idea if `System.Console` even exists for Xamarin Forms...

Comment: You should be using `Debug.WriteLine` instead as `System.Console` does not exist in PCL. Similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675897/1048571 / http://brianlagunas.com/write-platform-specific-code-with-a-portable-class-library-pcl/

Comment: can you add a module to VS to get use of `Console` when developing for Xamarin?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since your code is in a PCL with a specific profile the `System.Console` isn't available.

Use `Debug.WriteLine("Text here")` instead, don't forget to add `using System.Diagnostics;`.

Comment: It should be noted that it's a limitation of the PCL Profile they are using as they do not ship with `System.Console` but rather `Debug.WriteLine` instead. `ContentPage` is merely a class in Xamarin.Forms

Comment: @JonDouglas how is Debug.WriteLine is an alternative for Console.WriteLine? They are independent.

Comment: @JonDouglas updated the answer, but i just kept it simple for the sake of solving the problem. but thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov They are independent. You are correct in that respect. It's an alternative to logging respective information to an IDE (XS/VS) `Console Output` when using a shared PCL project. You can see that at the bottom, there's no support for PCL in the `Console` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx However there is support for PCL in the `Debug` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JonDouglas  I only mentioned it because your phrase (at least as I understood it) had a meaning that Debug.WriteLine is **shipped** instead of Console.WriteLine. Like the architect of the platform decided to use Debug.WriteLine to handle any console output)))

Comment: @jzeferino ah, k, I'll delete the comment then

Comment: replacing Console with Debug did the trick thank you very Much!

Comment: Coming from XCode, this Xamarin really sucks. You gotta import to log??? WTF!!! ANyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's because of the PCL. sometimes it could be frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

Declaring `using System;` at the beginning of the code also works.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `System.Console.WriteLine("text");` to Display output

Comment: note this question already ha accepted answer, much more complete than this one

Comment: also note the age of it, 6 years!

Answer (score 1):

The **"Console"** function is only available if you create a **Console App(.NET Core) or (.Net Framework)**; so, if you for example create a Blank App, it is not going to work. But instead, you can use the **Debug** function.